# regex to get part of string from end

Tags: regex

I have some URLs like

`http://wac.0E23.ed2323sdf.net/800E13/www.myexample.gr/`

`http://wac.0E22.ed2323sdf.net/812E13/www.my1example.gr/`

`http://wac.0E23.ed2323sdf.net/802E13/www.my2example.gr/`

I have to write regular expression to get the site name i.e `www.myexample.gr`, `www.my1example.gr` and `www.my2example.gr`

I wrote an expression to find the last occurrence of `/` but I am not able to capture the string between second last `/`.

Any idea how to achieve this?.

Regards,

Comment: can you post the regex that you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what language you're using (perl? elisp?). Usually, that would be extracted by the following:

```
"/([^/]+)/$"
```

where I put the regex between `"`. I do that because most languages use `//` as a search pattern definition in itself. And, depending on the language, the result would be in the first parenthesis value (in some languages `\1`, in others `$1`, in others `(match-string 1)`...)

Comment: I was trying ([^/])+/$....Can you please explain It will help me to understand what I was doing wrong.....

Comment: Well, the `+` has to be inside the parenthesis to match several characters inside the group.

Comment: you are matching string between  / from end right?...can you please tell me [^/] is useful here..

Comment: `[^/]` means a character *not* `/`, so what you do is try to get all the characters that are consecutive, and not `/`, and that are followed by a `/` *and* and end of line (or end of string).

Answer (score 2):

How about this expression:

```
~([^/]+)/$~
```